# Numbering visible items in with Slick carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the slick.js to show a grid of 6 items (2 rows, 3 column) per slide. I need normal prev and next arrow navigation, but also wish to display the active item count as a form of pagination help.

So if on the second slide, the text should read 'Showing 7 - 12 of x results'. I can only find ways to show slide number, not item, and this text needs to update whenever the slides are navigated through.

Unless there is a slick option that I haven't found, I'd have to loop through all the items,  indexing them all with numbers and find what ones have the parent class '.slick-active'. But I haven't been successful.

I'm also struggling to show the total items, as the closest thing slick seems to offer is slidecount, but that's related to the slides, not the items within.

One catch is these items won't always be a perfect multiple of 6, so the last page is likely to have less than 6 items.

Codepen attached. Many thanks!

```js
$('.carousel').slick({
  rows: 2,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3,
  autoplay: false,
  arrows: true,
  infinite: false,
  draggable: false,
  prevArrow: $('.prev'),
  nextArrow: $('.next')
});
```

```css
.item {
  background: silver;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline;
  border: 5px solid white;
}
.nav {
  width: 100%;
}
.nav p{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.results {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.js"></script>


<div class="carousel">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
  <div class="item">15</div>
  <div class="item">16</div>
  <div class="item">17</div>
  <div class="item">18</div>
</div>
<div class="nav">
  <p class="prev">prev</p>
  <p class="next">next</p>
</div>
<div class="results">
  Showing 1 to 9 of [total] results
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an Demo using `init` and `afterChange` [events](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#settings)

**Note:** Instead of `html()` use [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) wherever possible

```js
$('.carousel').on('init afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
  let total = $('.carousel .item').length;
  let start = $('.carousel .slick-active:first .item:first').html();
  let end = $('.carousel .slick-active:last .item:last').html();
  
  $('.results').html(`Showing ${start} to ${end} of ${total} results`)
})

$('.carousel').slick({
  rows: 2,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3,
  autoplay: false,
  arrows: true,
  infinite: false,
  draggable: false,
  prevArrow: $('.prev'),
  nextArrow: $('.next')
})
```

```css
.item {
  background: silver;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline;
  border: 5px solid white;
}
.nav {
  width: 100%;
}
.nav p{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.results {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.js"></script>


<div class="carousel">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
  <div class="item">15</div>
  <div class="item">16</div>
  <div class="item">17</div>
  <div class="item">18</div>
</div>
<div class="nav">
  <p class="prev">prev</p>
  <p class="next">next</p>
</div>
<div class="results">
  Showing 1 to 9 of [total] results
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, wish this was natively available from Slick.

Answer (score 3):

I have modified Aswin's answer to display currently active index of the visible slides, instead of reading data/html attribute.

```
$('.carousel').on('init afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
    let total = $('.carousel .item').length;
    var first = $('.slick-active:first > div:first').get(0);
    var last = $('.slick-active:last > div:last').get(0);
  if($(last).html() == '')
    last = $('.slick-active:last > div:not(:empty)').get(0);
    let start,end;
    $('.slick-slide > div').each(function(i,v){
        if(first === $(v).get(0)) {
            start = i+1;
        } 
        if(last === $(v).get(0)) {
            end = i+1;
        }
    });
  $('.results').html(`Showing ${start} to ${end} of ${total} results`)
})
$('.carousel').slick({
  rows: 2,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3,
  autoplay: false,
  arrows: true,
  infinite: false,
  draggable: false,
  prevArrow: $('.prev'),
  nextArrow: $('.next')
})
```

```css
.item {
  background: silver;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline;
  border: 5px solid white;
}
.nav {
  width: 100%;
}
.nav p{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.results {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.js"></script>


<div class="carousel">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
  <div class="item">15</div>
  <div class="item">16</div>
  <div class="item">17</div>
  <div class="item">18</div>
</div>
<div class="nav">
  <p class="prev">prev</p>
  <p class="next">next</p>
</div>
<div class="results">
  Showing 1 to 9 of [total] results
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Only catch is if I remove the last div so there are only 17 results, the text on the last slide still says:

Showing 13 to 18 of 17 results

So the overall result count is updating but not the 'out of' number.

Do you know what that would be?

Comment: Updated answer. please check. You can pick not empty div OR first div from the last section. and mark it accepted if it solves your question :)